# How to handle navigation in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

In Jetpack Compose, how is navigation supposed to be done? All (and there aren’t many) examples (including the official sample from Google) use sealed classes and loading new screens in reaction to observing the change in the current screen. This does (sort of) work, but provides no navigation backstack, and the phone’s back button is totally unaware, just closes the app instead of going back to the previous screen. Is this supposed to somehow converge with the navigation component from AndroidX - but it’s XML based, and Compose is all about moving away from XML? Or is there a brand new navigation concept coming, perhaps similar to SwiftUI (navigationlink, etc)? This seems to be one of the biggest roadblocks - as without navigation you can only have a toy app. Anyone aware of the roadmap here?

Comment: "Is this supposed to somehow converge with the navigation component from AndroidX" -- yes. "Compose is all about moving away from XML" -- no, Compose is all about moving away from the `View` hierarchy. That has a side effect of eliminating traditional layout resources. That does not eliminate the vast majority of resources. "Anyone aware of the roadmap here?" -- it is all very much a work in progress.

Comment: thanks. Understood its work in progress, but I think knowing the roadmap has very practical implications - for example, is it worth investing in learning a new way of doing things (AndroidX navigation) if it is going to be superseded by something else once Compose takes off. They have been working on Compose for some time now, and surely as big a thing as navigation must have some architectural roadmap at least, and no internet search revealed anything about that roadmap

Comment: All that I have seen indicates that their intention is to leverage the Navigation component. I can all but guarantee that other developers will create other "router" options, leveraging React/Redux sorts of techniques. So, I expect that you will have a range of options to choose from by the time Jetpack Compose is ready for production use.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

New Jetpack lib has published for Compose navigation. It is still in alpha.

In this new library, now user can able to navigation between different composables with navigation components features.

Using **navigation-compose**:

```
dependencies {
    def nav_compose_version = "1.0.0-alpha01"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:$nav_compose_version"
}
```

**Example:**

**Step 1:** create a `NavController` by using the `rememberNavController()` method in your composable: [Link](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation#getting-started):

```
val navController = rememberNavController()
```

**Step 2:** Creating the `NavHost` requires the `NavController` previously created via `rememberNavController()` and the route of the starting destination of your graph:[Link](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation#create-navhost).

```
NavHost(navController, startDestination = "profile") {
    composable("profile") { Profile(...) }
    composable("friendslist") { FriendsList(...) }
    ...
}
```

**Step 3:** To navigate to a composable use `navigate()`:

```
fun Profile(navController: NavController) {
    ...
    Button(onClick = { navController.navigate("friends") }) {
        Text(text = "Navigate next")
    }
    ...
}
```

check more https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation

Comment: `navController.navigate("friends")` seems to not work. It returns compile error. `None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied.
navigate(Uri) defined in androidx.navigation.NavController
navigate(NavDeepLinkRequest) defined in androidx.navigation.NavController
navigate(NavDirections) defined in androidx.navigation.NavController
navigate(Int) defined in androidx.navigation.NavController`

Comment: @Thracian I don't know why, but AS couldn't find new 'navigate' extension that is used in documentation here, so I had to manually import it like this:

`import androidx.navigation.compose.navigate`

Comment: that's because you need to call `navController.navigate("friendslist")` with the right label.

Answer (score 11):

Here is an unofficial approach of navigation in Jetpack Compose. Try it out until you get an official word from the Google android devs.

**compose-router**

https://github.com/zsoltk/compose-router

Answer (score 8):

Use `androidx.navigation:navigation-compose`. See @pRaNaY's answer.

##### Original Answer

It seems that they are moving away from XML.

The new official samples released after the release of 1.0.0-alpha, have a shared code to manage backstack and navigation. This code is not part of the library yet.

https://github.com/android/compose-samples/blob/master/Owl/app/src/main/java/com/example/owl/ui/utils/Navigation.kt
https://github.com/android/compose-samples/blob/master/Jetsnack/app/src/main/java/com/example/jetsnack/ui/utils/Navigation.kt

##### Update

Because sample projects are migrated to `androidx.navigation:navigation-compose`, links are dead.
I tried to find the most up to date commits which links are not dead.

https://github.com/android/compose-samples/blob/17b362f0315cf786d3d77d6964ee39b50e311199/Owl/app/src/main/java/com/example/owl/ui/utils/Navigation.kt

https://github.com/android/compose-samples/blob/17b362f0315cf786d3d77d6964ee39b50e311199/Jetsnack/app/src/main/java/com/example/jetsnack/ui/utils/Navigation.kt

Comment: 404 not found...

Comment: @Morozov updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I have writed how to handle Navigation with Jetpack Compose

Link : https://medium.com/@gsaillen95/how-to-handle-navigation-in-jetpack-compose-a9ac47f7f975

Answer (score 1):

Here is another good alternative library for Compose Navigation:

https://github.com/olshevski/compose-navigation-reimagined

I've created it because some parts of the official Navigation Component are too much weird.